# Messages: is this Apple Support or a scam

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I had an issue with my phone. I was going to call Apple Support, but it was pretty late and they were not picking up calls, so I decided to text. After sending messages to the number (800)-692-7753, I had no clue if this was legitimate or not. I asked them if they were legitimate, they actually used my first name so I don't know. I heard of phishing stuff in the past, and I could not tell if this was it. Messages claims it's verified, but I don't know if I can be sure. If someone could please verify this, it would be much appreciated.

On iMessage if I click on the profile, it says:

> Apple
> Electronics Store
> Verified

Edit: Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you include a screenshot of the message and the number's profile as well?

Comment: Perhaps you use the apple support website and go to the chat. It should send grey messages (usually sends blue).

Comment: I just added it

Comment: @SkylineX I just posted a screenshot, and my messages were grey

Comment: Hi Ralph, it looks pretty legit to me with the verified tick. Maybe let's see what the others think?

Comment: It looks legit but I straight up asked them if they were apple and their response was that it was the official number, and then they used my first name which was odd

Comment: Where did you get the number from in the first place?

Comment: Why do you think it's odd that they know your name? If you have registered with them, of course the will; and some reps include that information specifically to indicate that they have a prior relationship with you; though if it's easy to find your first name from public records, that could just be something the scammer decided to try to imitate. (But spending time on making the scam credible is often something they will not do; they would engage in higher-stakes fraud if they spent actual time on you.)

Comment: @nohillside I got the number from the web

Comment: @tripleee it's just odd because I don't know how easy it is for someone to get your name from number or something like that

Comment: As long as the messages that I send are grey rather then blue or green, it should be fine correct? This is in the messages app by the way.

Comment: That seems legit

Comment: @RalphK it isn't odd that they know your name because when I talk to them, they use my name. they see your Apple ID ( I think) and have some way of knowing its you.

Answer (score 1):

A quick visit to Apple's [Support webpage](https://www.apple.com/contact/) shows that the number is genuine.

If you sent messages to that number, and then shortly afterwards you got a call from them, then I'd say it's highly likely that it's Apple.

It could, of course, be someone spoofing Apple's number. But if you're not prepared to trust an incoming call, then you'll have to initiate the call and queue on the line.

Comment: I did not get a call from them, but that might be because it was after the call hours, but also my messages were grey when I was sending them. @benwiggy

Answer (score 0):

The phone is genuine. I text the same number when I have problems sometimes. It also says it is a verfied number and has a contact name which Apple puts on their phones automatically so you can, ironically, trust them.